# Add Date and Time stamp to powershell exported file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am new to scripting but at my work place I see that they are storing warnings, errors and notes from logs of different programs under one file using the below command in a batch file:
check_log.bat > tlglogs

PS: If it matters the different logs and the output tlglogs are in the same Windows folder.

I would like to add a date time stamp to the tlglogs each time I run the batch file. Could you please let me know how to proceed as I am not familiar with scripting? I tried the below via Dr. Google's help but it did not help:
check_log.bat >tlglogs_%Date%

Thanks for your time and help. It is highly appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you can get the current date like below:

```
Get-Date
```

You can save it to a variable and also define the format of the returned date.

```
$d = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
```

So this will return a date in the format like 04082016 and save it in the variable $d which we can use for export.

```
check_log.bat > "tlglogs_$d"
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: Put the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` order, and the files will sort into chronological order neatly.

Comment: Thanks Junaid, but when I run it I get the output as tlglogs_$d, so $d is not being resolved to the actual date value for some reason.

Comment: Remake, did you first set $d to the current date value? If you just type $d on the terminal and hit enter does it print the date or not? If not then make sure to set $d = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-mm-dd" and then run the second command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Junaid, adding the below code in the batch file worked for me:

```
@echo off

set startDate=%date%
set startTime=%time%

set sdy=%startDate:~10%
set /a sdm=1%startDate:~4,2% - 100
set /a sdd=1%startDate:~7,2% - 100
set /a sth=%startTime:~0,2%
set /a stm=1%startTime:~3,2% - 100
set /a sts=1%startTime:~6,2% - 100


check_log.bat *.log > tlglogs%sdy%.%sdm%.%sdd%-%sth%.%stm%
```

If there is a much easier way please do let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: You could create a simple powershell file with the command as shown in previous answer.